# How to insert many if not in database

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

So I finally figured out on how to use insert_many. My code is mostly based out of emails however I did figure out that if I use insert_many with same emails, they will all be added and I would like to make a sort check where I check if email is already in the DB then don't insert it else insert it pretty much.

```
emailList = []
for emails in getEmailFile:
    if not db.license.find_one({'email': emails}): #updated
         emailList.append({'email': emails.lower().replace("\r","").strip(), "MAC": 0, "key_resets": 0, "raffleItem": []})

db.license.insert_many(emailList)
```

Using this code does work and does add up all the collections and elements as it should however I would like to make a sort check where it checks first if Email is in the DB before it actually inserts it. How would you guys help me out with that?

Comment: you should create a UNIQUE INDEX: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: Also, you could `db.collection.updateMany()` with upsert

Comment: Oh im so confused, What is the difference between if I do it with insert_many and the unique index and updateMany() ? @felipsmartins

Comment: @felipsmartins I edited the thread where I did a find_one. What do you think about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way of achieving this is to create a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/index.html) on the email field and use the `{ordered: false}` option of `insertMany()` to make an [unordered insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html#unordered-inserts). What this does is insert all the emails that don't exist and generate an error for the duplicate emails. Thus:

```
db.license.insert_many(emailList, ordered=False)
```

Note that you will still need to handle the error returned by pymongo.

Comment: hmm im not sure how this would work. Does ordered=False actually solve the "multiply same email" in the DB? I did something small changes where I added a check of ```if not db.license.find_one({'email': emails}):``` before I send to insert_many but if its correct I am not sure?

Comment: I added the thread where I did a find_one. What do you think about that?

Comment: The `find_one()` will work but makes a lot of queries to the database so it will not be good from a performance point of view. Creating the unique index and using `ordered=False` makes only one query. If the email already exists, its insert will be discarded, if it does not exist it will be inserted.

Comment: What do you mean by creating a unique index? Isnt my emailList a unique one or is it something else? If you could maybe provide an example of how I can get further would be really really appreciated! Because what you just mentioned is something I am looking for.

Comment: I mean create an index in the database for the `email` field, like this: `db.license.create_index('email', unique=True )`

Comment: Do I need to create index for every new email or just once?

Comment: Just once, it will stay there and be updated every time you modify the data in the database. My advice is to look at how indexes work in general, it is a common element in all databases, not just MongoDB.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks alot and I can mark this as answer to my question! - Took some time to get it to work with the error handle but I got it :)